# Compiling program is not give me permission2 execute outpt of clang -o user.o|can't run user.o w/ sudo says command not found or sudo permision denied

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ebpf, xdp-bpf

So I compiled xdp program like

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

```
 sudo clang -Wall -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I /usr/lib/usr/include/ -c af_xdp_user.c -o user.o
```

or

```
 sudo clang -Wall -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I /usr/lib/usr/include/ -c af_xdp_user.c -o user.o  -lbpf
```

generates user.o

but there is no use of user.o since ls -a not showing x just showing -wr for read write. when i run it like `sudo ./user.o` message says `sudo: ./user.o: command not found` or without sudo `bash: ./user.o: Permission denied` so what eactly why I am unable to run the .o file, I used tro generate .o file and execute the like simple main program not using any libray or anything shared. I also tried to `-o user` and try to execute ./user but same problem.

Can anyone please inform what am I doing wrong

Comment: The object file you compiled with that command contains the BPF programs and related information (e.g., maps). You then need to write a second program, usually called the loader, to load the BPF programs. Most tutorials should include both.

Comment: Compilation alone is not enough to produce an executable. You need to link it, too.

Comment: @pchaigno yes this question is about loader program in ebpf xdp..

Comment: Oh, right. Of course :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add execute permissions to the file. Write this command in the terminal to do it:

```
sudo chmod a+x user.o
```

This command will add to all users execute permissions, so just typing

```
./user.o
```

will run the file.

---

If you don't want all users to be able to run the file, you can add execute permissions only to root, like this:

```
sudo chmod u+x user.o
```

In this case you will be able to run the program by typing

```
sudo ./user.o
```